# Subsequently sending command-line arguments to a C program without re-executing it

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, command-line-arguments

I am currently using 
$./launch argv1 argv2 argv3 
template to send command line arguments to my c program. However, I want to launch my program once, and want to send my arguments without typing "./launch" part (basically a for loop that asks for input every round). I basically want that whenever I type something, my program interpretes as I am sending arguments to it. I know that I should use pthread and stuff but I don't really know how to do it and I am kinda new to this, so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need pthreads to read from an input stream (`stdin`).

Comment: If you shared a code snippet with the community showing what your code is doing, they can give you a better answer and/or suggestion on how to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I basically want that whenever I type something, my program interpretes as I am sending arguments to it.

It does not work that way, sorry.  Program arguments are passed to a program only when it starts, as a part of starting it.

Afterward, your program can *read* additional data from its standard input or other sources, but such data is not received in the form of program arguments.  If you wish, you can process them the same way you do your program's arguments, but that would be unusual.  Usually, programs use arguments and I/O for different purposes.

> I know that I should use pthread and stuff

I have no clue what gave you the idea that pthreads should have a role to play here, and I urge you to develop a good working understanding of how single-threaded code and programs work before you consider delving into pthreads or any other multi-threading API.